# Как сделать, чтобы slick слайдером можно было управлять колёсиком мыши?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, slider

мне надо сделать так, чтобы в slick слайдере можно было управлять колёсиком мыши, пример [тут](https://cuberto.ru)
Мой код:
[код на codepen](https://codepen.io/Belzer/pen/gOGqwJm)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slider').slick({
        vertical: true,
        verticalSwiping: true,
        touchThreshold: true

    });
});
```

Comment: Люди поставившие мне минус, в чём проблема-то? Что я сделал, зачем занижать мне рейтинг. Если для вас вопрос кажется глупым, не смотрите его!

Comment: А как "включить" скролл страницы при прокрутке к последнему слайду?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Должно сработать

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.slider').slick({
            vertical: true,
            verticalSwiping: true,
            touchThreshold: true

        });
          $('.slider').on('wheel', (function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
            $(this).slick('slickNext');
        } else {
            $(this).slick('slickPrev');
        }
    }));
(jQuery);
    });
```

```css
.slider {
    height: 100vh;
    &-text {
        padding-top: 50px;
        font-size: 48px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    &-block {
        height: calc(100vh - 27%);
        &-item {
            padding-top: 150px;
            font-size: 18px;
        }
        &-title {
            padding: 20px 0px;
            font-size: 36px;
        }
        &-description {
            font-size: 18px;
            color: rgba($color: #ffffff, $alpha: .7);
        }
        &-img {
            padding-top: 50px;
            float: right;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/slick.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
    
<section class="portfolio">
        <a name="portfolio"></a>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h2 class="slider-text">Наше портфолио</h2>
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="slider-block">
                    <img class="slider-block-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/3ZszTEL.png" alt="">
                    <p class="slider-block-item">PORSCHE</p>
                    <p class="slider-block-title">Немецкий производитель<br>премиальных автомобилей</p>
                    <p class="slider-block-description">web, landing, product</p>
                </div>
                <div class="slider-block">
                    <img class="slider-block-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/3ZszTEL.png" alt="">
                    <p class="slider-block-item">PORSCHE</p>
                    <p class="slider-block-title">Немецкий производитель<br>премиальных автомобилей</p>
                    <p class="slider-block-description">web, landing, product</p>
                </div>
                <div class="slider-block">
                    <img class="slider-block-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/3ZszTEL.png" alt="">
                    <p class="slider-block-item">PORSCHE</p>
                    <p class="slider-block-title">Немецкий производитель<br>премиальных автомобилей</p>
                    <p class="slider-block-description">web, landing, product</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```

А если надо горизонтальны скролл, то вот так

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.slider').slick({
            horizontal: true,
            horizontalSwiping: true,
            touchThreshold: true

        });
          $('.slider').on('wheel', (function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
            $(this).slick('slickNext');
        } else {
            $(this).slick('slickPrev');
        }
    }));
(jQuery);
    });
```

```css
.slider {
    height: 100vh;
    &-text {
        padding-top: 50px;
        font-size: 48px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    &-block {
        height: calc(100vh - 27%);
        &-item {
            padding-top: 150px;
            font-size: 18px;
        }
        &-title {
            padding: 20px 0px;
            font-size: 36px;
        }
        &-description {
            font-size: 18px;
            color: rgba($color: #ffffff, $alpha: .7);
        }
        &-img {
            padding-top: 50px;
            float: right;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/slick.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
    
<section class="portfolio">
        <a name="portfolio"></a>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h2 class="slider-text">Наше портфолио</h2>
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="slider-block">
                    <img class="slider-block-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/3ZszTEL.png" alt="">
                    <p class="slider-block-item">PORSCHE</p>
                    <p class="slider-block-title">Немецкий производитель<br>премиальных автомобилей</p>
                    <p class="slider-block-description">web, landing, product</p>
                </div>
                <div class="slider-block">
                    <img class="slider-block-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/3ZszTEL.png" alt="">
                    <p class="slider-block-item">PORSCHE</p>
                    <p class="slider-block-title">Немецкий производитель<br>премиальных автомобилей</p>
                    <p class="slider-block-description">web, landing, product</p>
                </div>
                <div class="slider-block">
                    <img class="slider-block-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/3ZszTEL.png" alt="">
                    <p class="slider-block-item">PORSCHE</p>
                    <p class="slider-block-title">Немецкий производитель<br>премиальных автомобилей</p>
                    <p class="slider-block-description">web, landing, product</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: К сожалению не работает :(

Comment: @Belzer Исправил ответ     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.slider').slick({
            horizontalSwiping: true,
            touchThreshold: true,
          horizontal: true,
          slidesToScroll: 1
        });
    });

Comment: @Belzer Посмотрите мой исправленный ответ